# kohana validation during update

Tags: php, kohana

In my application developed using Kohana, I have a form where user enters their registration information, My rules are correctly executing and the error message is displaying correctly if user ignores an important field or enters an email address in inappropriate form.

The problem is that i want to do the same validations while an his personal information at a later point of time, but i want to ignore the password fields which is usually empty when the form loads.

- Is it really possible to make kohana ignore the blank password values
  while updating?
- I am using the following  code to update user data, I could see no
  validation is performed(which is defined in my `Model_User`) when i use
  `update_user()` of Auth. Can somebody please throw some light on
  potential issues that hinders the execution of validation routines
  here?

```
if(Auth::instance()->logged_in()) {
    $values =  array();
    $now = new DateTime();
     $userobj = Auth::instance()->get_user();

    //$userobj->updatedon = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // need research
    try {
        $userobj->update_user($_POST, array('email',
                                            'password',
                                            'firstname',
                                            'secondname',
                                            'lastname',
                                            'phone',
                                            'city_id'
        ));
        $values = Auth::instance()->get_user()->as_array();
    } catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
         $errors = $e->errors('models');
    }
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem. When registering users, make sure to use [`create_user()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#create_user) and add password specific rules to [`get_password_validation()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#get_password_validation).

Now the logic will only apply for registration and not for updating already existing users.

Also if you don't want to update the `password`, make sure to remove it from the list.

```
$updateColumns = array('email', 'password', ...);
if ( ! isSet($_POST['password']) || trim($_POST['password']) == "") {
    unset($updateColumns[1]);
}
$userobj->update_user($_POST, $updateColumns);
```